# No qualifying bean of type found for service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Boa Noite pessoal, estou tentando lançar um API Spring e estou com o seguinte problema na execução dele, já tentei renomear os métodos assim como as funções

Primeiro vou deixar o Debug log aqui

> Field service in com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.controller.ControladorCurso required a bean of type 'com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.service.ServicoCurso' that could not be
> found.
>
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.service.ServicoCurso' in your configuration.

Antes disso na hora de rodar a aplicação aparece este erro aqui, caso ajude também:

> 2020-08-12 21:04:26.806  WARN 13260 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controladorCurso': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.service.ServicoCurso' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Segue minha Classe Curso:

```
package com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "CURSOS_TBL")

public class Curso {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String nome_curso;
    private String duracao;
    private String area_atuacao;
    private String portaria_mec;
    private String ementa;
    private double valor_mensalidade;
    private int qtde_vagas;
}
```

Segue minha Classe ServicoCurso.java

```
package com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.service;

import java.util.List;
import com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.entity.Curso;
import com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.repository.RepositorioCurso;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class ServicoCurso {
    @Autowired
    private RepositorioCurso repository;
    
    public Curso saveCurso(Curso curso){
        return repository.save(curso);
    }
    public List<Curso> saveCursos(List<Curso> cursos){
        return repository.saveAll(cursos);
    }

    public List<Curso> getCursos(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Curso getCursoById(int id){
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Curso getCursoByName(String name){
        return repository.findByName(name);
    }

    public String deleteCurso(int id){
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return "curso removido = "+id;
    }

    public Curso updateCurso(Curso curso){
        Curso existingCurso = repository.findById(curso.getId()).orElse(null);
        existingCurso.setNome_curso(curso.getNome_curso());
        existingCurso.setDuracao(curso.getDuracao());
        existingCurso.setArea_atuacao(curso.getArea_atuacao());
        existingCurso.setEmenta(curso.getEmenta());
        existingCurso.setPortaria_mec(curso.getPortaria_mec());
        existingCurso.setValor_mensalidade(curso.getValor_mensalidade());
        existingCurso.setQtde_vagas(curso.getQtde_vagas());

        return repository.save(existingCurso);
    }
    
}
```

Segue Meu ControladorCurso.java

```
package com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.controller;

import java.util.List;

import com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.entity.Curso;
import com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.service.ServicoCurso;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class ControladorCurso {

    @Autowired
    private ServicoCurso service;

    @PostMapping("/addCurso")
    private Curso addCurso(@RequestBody Curso curso){
        return service.saveCurso(curso);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addCursos")
    private List<Curso> addCursos(@RequestBody List<Curso> cursos){
        return service.saveCursos(cursos);
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscaCursos")
    public List<Curso> findAllCursos() {
        return service.getCursos();
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscaCursosById/{id}")
    public Curso findCursosById(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.getCursoById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscaCursos/{name}")
    public Curso findcursoById(@PathVariable String nome){
        return service.getCursoByName(nome);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateCurso")
    public Curso updateCurso(@RequestBody Curso curso){
        return service.updateCurso(curso);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteCurso/{id}")
    public String deleteCurso(@RequestBody int id){
        return service.deleteCurso(id);
    }
    
}
```

e Segue meu RepositorioCurso.java

```
package com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.repository;

import com.zaleski.apieadteste.apieadteste.entity.Curso;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RepositorioCurso extends JpaRepository<Curso,Integer> {
    Curso findByName(String nome_curso);
}
```

Qualquer Ajuda é bem vinda, grato

Answer (score 1):

Você esqueceu a anotação [@Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) em sua classe `ServicoCurso`. A anotação vai torná-la detectável pelo Spring, e, por conta disso, estar disponível para injeção na sua controladora:

```
@Service
public class ServicoCurso {
    ...
}
```